# How to solve integrity constraint violation in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am getting the following error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `answers` (`body`, `user_id`, `question_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

I am trying to submit an answer to a form using Laravel and I am getting the above error. First I checked my schema in my answers table and the user_id is correctly defined:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('question_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('votes_count')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Next I added this code to my AnswersController.php to validate the code and redirect once the answer is submitted:

```
public function store(Question $question, Request $request)
{    
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    $question->answers()->create(['body' => $request->body, 'user_id' => \Auth::id()]);

    return back()->with('success', "Your answer has been submitted successfully");
}
```

I imported the Answer class into my AnswersController.php and I also made the body and user_id fields into fillable in the Answer.php model:

```
protected $fillable = ['body', 'user_id'];
```

When I click the submit button on my form, I get the SQL State error shown above. user_id is a valid field in my DB answers table. I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  But the error is pretty straightforward: you are not getting a `user_id`.   IE you are trying to create an answer pivot, calling `user_id` to be created from a non-object.  \Auth::id() is empty or not recognized for what you want.  Call the user object instead.

Try this:

```
$question->answers()->create(['body' => $request->body, 'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id]);
```

Also make sure you actually have a user:  send the form back through a route with the auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   Route::resource('questions.answers', 'AnswersController');
   // Any other routes where you want a user
}
```

Comment: Hi, Watercayman, I used your code snippet and when I ran the code, I got this error now: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: That's a good sign - it shows the issue.  Is this form coming in through (routed) the normal Laravel auth middleware?  If not, you wont' have a user, and thus the error. I'll edit my answer to help

Comment: No sure what you mean by "is this form coming in through (routed) - sorry I am new to laravel. But I have this route in my web.php:   Route::resource('questions.answers', 'AnswersController')->except(['index', 'create', 'show']);

Comment: No problem - make sure that route is inside your auth middleware - see the edited answer -- also - if you don't have 'create' inside, that will be a problem - need to have create

Comment: Which file do I put the above Route::group code in?

Comment: Sec - I'll edit with your route.  This is all inside your web.php file - we're just making sure it goes through the middleware to get your user